# HP Notebook 17-y020ca under XUbuntu 16.04 unable to resume from suspend

Tags: 16.04, suspend, crash

I recently purchased an HP Notebook 17-y020ca and installed Ubuntu 16.04. I originally had to overcome some WiFi issues with the Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 wireless card, but now that side of things appears to be working well.

Unfortunately, there is a fatal issue remaining: the laptop is completely unable to resume after suspending.  This behavior is deterministic -- while suspend appears to place the computer in a standard "suspended" state (with a slowly blinking light), a resume following a suspension yields a slightly glowing screen with no text or indication of display of any content.  Perhaps most notably, the disk light flickers occasionally (suggesting that some processes remain active), but the computer is completely unresponsive.

Control-Alt-F1 (which normally brings me to another console) does nothing  While it is possible that this is simply a display problem, I have not been able to escape via anything but a complete shutdown.

As the video device is often suspect in similar problems experienced by others, I would note that the information on my video card (as output from  "lspci -vnn | grep -A12 VGA") is as follows:

> 00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Carrizo [1002:9874] (rev ca) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
>     DeviceName: ATI UMA EG BROADWAY
>     Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Carrizo [103c:8221]
>     Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 226
>     Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
>     Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=8M]
>     I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
>     Memory at f0d00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
>     Expansion ROM at f0d80000 [disabled] [size=128K]
>     Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 
>     Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
>     Capabilities: [58] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
>     Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+`

Contents of/var/log/pm-suspend.log on my computer can be found [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/18010440/).

The following is the contents of my /proc/cmdline

`BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.4.0-21-generic.efi.signed root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7`

Please note that an upgrade of the kernel to 4.4.8 (as advocated on many other threads involving suspend/resume problems) does not solve this problem.

While I have investigated it less closely, I would note that hibernate/unhibernate also reliably fails on this machine.

I would be truly grateful for any suggestions that anyone could give.  I would be happy to share output from journalctl, dmesg or other tools if readers think that this may be of help.  I much appreciate your consideration!

Sincerely,

Nathaniel Osgood

Comment: Please note that while suspend itself appears to place the computer in a standard "suspended" state (with a slowly blinking light), it is the resume  following the suspend that causes trouble (as above, it yields a slightly glowing screen with no text or indication of display of any content.)  I hope that this clarification helps in understanding the issue.

Comment: For those who are interested in seeing my  /var/log/pm-suspend.log, it can be found here on pastebin: [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/18010440/)

Answer (score 0):

After much research, experimentation and observation, I found the problem above that was the machine was indeed resuming almost entirely -- it was simply not properly setting the video state so that the monitor was on and displaying contents.  I am not sure if this was due to a bug in the amdgpu driver, elsewhere in the kernel, but I found that the easiest way to resolve this was to ignore the man page information for pm-suspend regarding the antiquated character of "--quirk-radeon-off", and indeed to  use that option as follows:

pm-suspend --quirk-radeon-off

Upon resuming, the system resets the video card in the correct state, and the system works well.

I hope that this discovery is of use to others with HP Pavilion laptops, or other similar laptops.  I appreciate all of those who gave my problem some thought.